# ERROR -> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, youtube-api, dotenv

This is the ERROR

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () at authorize (c:\Users\xxxx\server.js:21:30)
> at main (c:\Users\xxxx\server.js:11:22)
> at Object. (c:\Users\xxxx\server.js:7:1)

```
    function authorize() {
        //Error occured at this line
        const credentials = JSON.parse(process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
    }
```

.env file

```
    CLIENT_SECRET ={
        "installed": {
            "client_id": "xxxx",
            "project_id": "xxxx",
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
            "client_secret": "xxxx",
            "redirect_uris": [
                "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
                "http://localhost"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `.env` file's contents **aren't JSON**, it's JavaScript code assigning to a variable (which is undeclared). To make it JSON, remove the `CLIENT_SECRET =` part. (More about what JSON is and isn't [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247).)

Comment: Your file does not contain a valid JSON text; that's due to this fragment `CLIENT_SECRET =`.

Comment: I think .env files don't support objects/JSON, only simple lines of `variable=string`. `CLIENT_SECRET ={` is one line (JSON.parse believes that's all there is) and `"installed": {` another independent line, so it's considered a syntax error